# SourceTree: error: pathspec 'Assets\017AssetData/.../Lightmap-1778_comp_light.exr' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: unity-game-engine, atlassian-sourcetree

I wanted to discard/delete one mysterious file.(that is from somebody)

The path is`'Client/Assets\017AssetData/Scenes/LightingPronteraMaster_ProgressiveNew_E/Lightmap-1778_comp_light.exr'`.

Once I discarded it. There was an error log.

```
    git
-c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks checkout --
Client/Assets\017AssetData/Scenes/LightingPronteraMaster_ProgressiveNew_E/Lightmap-1778_comp_light.exr
error: pathspec 'Client/Assets\017AssetData/Scenes/LightingPronteraMaster_ProgressiveNew_E/Lightmap-1778_comp_light.exr' did not match any file(s) known to git
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I also checked on the project folder. And this file was no-found. I tried stash/ reset commit/ switch branch. None of these solution works.

** I noticed there is one back slash in the string path. While the rest are using normal slash. Is this mysterious \ related to this error?

Please help

[discard error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2TCQ.png)
[reset all changes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMphG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I checked out from my current to develop. The mystery file was completely gone! Then I switched back to my working branch again.

I guess it is a SourceTree error.